# how many observations will the data set contain?

Tags: sas

The following is the code:

```
data work.homework;
   infile 'file-specification';
   input name$ age height;
   if age le 10;
run;
```

The raw data file is listed as the following:

```
A  35  71
B  10  43
C  9   12
```

I thought the correct  answer should be 2. But it seems that it is 3 according to the answer sheet. Could anyone explain to me what is the reason? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Clear ask to solve a homework problem without attempting to solve the problem first.

Comment: Have you run the code? That should be the final answer and it isn't 3 in my results.

Comment: Suggest you try running the code and check the output dataset to see how many records it has, and what the values are of the variables.

Comment: I did not run it. It is just it does not make sense to me. Even if I run it and get the result 3, it still does not make sense to me.

Comment: 'if age le 10;' clearly means that we are looking for observations/records with the age filed less or equal than 10. In this case, there should be 2, instead of 3.

Comment: @DomPazz Seems like there's an attempt to solve the problem to me.  Homework has no special negative (or positive) status here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data work.homework;
   infile datalines;
   input name$ age height;
   if age le 10;
   datalines;
A  35  71
B  10  43
C  9   12
;;;;
run;
NOTE: The data set WORK.HOMEWORK has 2 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Now, as for how the answer might be three, I would look very carefully at the problem.  There are two potential pitfalls.

One: is it possible a fourth record is read in? One that has blanks?  If there is a blank line in the file, it's possible this would occur.  Blank is indeed less than or equal to ten (check it!), so this line would qualify.

Two: if the line is

```
if age le 10 then ... ;
```

Then the automatic output is not affected.

As long as the code and data are exactly as above, though, two rows will be the correct answer to "How many observations will the dataset contain".  (Not, how many observations will be *processed* in the data step loop, of course.)